# Error: "undefined" when uploading multiple files using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, multer

Route:

```js
router.post('/MOCReport', upload.array('files'), MOCReportController.MOCReport_post);
```

Controller:

```js
exports.MOCReport_post = (req, res, next) => {      const files = req.files;
      console.log(files.filename);
      if(!files){
          const error = new Error('Please upload an image')
          error.httpStatusCode = 400
          return next (error)
      }
      var paths = req.files.map(files => file.path)
      let newMOCReport = new MOCReport({
        facilityName: req.body.facilityName,
        MoCDescription: req.body.MoCDescription,
        MoCReportDateTime: req.body.MoCReportDateTime,
        MoCDisasterLocation: req.body.MoCDisasterLocation,
        mocImage: req.files.paths
      });
      newMOCReport.save().then((MOCReportDoc) => {
        res.send(MOCReportDoc);
      });
    };
Schema:

    mocImage:{
            type: Array,
            required: false
        },
```

Getting Error Undefined when uploading multiple images to mongoDB database with multer.

Error :
Listening to port 3000
Connected to MongoDB successfully :)

> undefined

POST /MoCReport 500 44.414 ms - 43

[image]

Comment: Please post the *exact* error you get.

Comment: The terminal just displayed "undefined", postman displays : file is not defined

Comment: That doesn't sound like an error, then. Sounds like you log something and the contents of the logged item is `undefined`.

Comment: I dont understand, it worked with a single image upload but when changing to upload.array it doesnt

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are sending all the files with the same name "**files**".

You can try to change this:

```js
upload.array('files')
```

to this:

```js
upload.any()
```

`any()` method will accept all the files. It will not check the name of the field.

Also, after this change, you have to change this line:

```js
 var paths = req.files.map(files => file.path);
```

You have an error there, because you are mapping `files` and you are accessing `file`. Change it like this:

```js
const paths = req.files.map(file => file.path);
```

Comment: it gives the same error :
`"error": {
        "message": "file is not defined"
    }`

Comment: Im testing using postman, ill post a picture

Comment: Wait, you don't have `file` anywhere in you code.

Comment: I updated the answer. Can you try it now?

Comment: it worked but the array is empty when submitting, i updated the picture to show whats the response sent

Comment: Try logging `files` in the console. and not `files.filename`.

Comment: There is no change, it isnt storing in the db

Answer (score 0):

Check this is the complete working code.

```
 const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const port = 3000
    const multer  = require('multer')
    const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
    
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('<form id="form_el" class=\'new-project\' action=\'/MOCReport\' method=\'POST\' enctype="multipart/form-data">\n' +
            '    <label for=\'file\'>Select your image:</label>\n' +
            '    <input type=\'file\' multiple=\'multiple\' accept=\'image/!*\' name=\'uploadedImages\' id=\'file\' />\n' +
            '    <span class=\'hint\'>Supported files: jpg, jpeg, png.</span>\n' +
            '    <button type=\'submit\'>upload</button>\n' +
            '</form>')
    })
    
    
    app.post('/MOCReport',upload.any(),function (req, res, next){
        const files = req.files;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(files));
    
        res.send('Uploaded successfully');
    });
    
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem

Please review the react code

Please check the structure to see if the file information is properly loaded in formdata.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).